# How to use variable in SSH config file

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I want to use `$HOME` to replace `/Users/Me` in my ssh config file

```
Host MyHost
    HostName 192.168.1.1
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User me
    IdentityFile "/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

but I got `no such identity: $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least on my Debian 10 system, the `ssh_config(5)` man page says:

> Arguments to **IdentityFile** may use the tilde syntax to refer to user's home directory or the tokens described in the TOKENS section.

So, instead of using `$HOME`, you can write the `IdentityFile` line either as:

```
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

or as:

```
IdentityFile "%d/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Environment variable syntax (`${HOME}`) support is only mentioned with the `IdentityAgent` configuration item, not with `IdentityFile`. According to [OpenSSH release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html), the environment variable syntax support was added to `CertificateFile`, `ControlPath` and `IdentityFile` configuration keywords in OpenSSH version 8.4 (released on 2020-09-27), and Debian 10 only has version 7.9 (with the latest security fixes backported).

So at the time of this writing, unless you are using a very new Linux distribution, your OpenSSH version might be too old to support using the `${HOME}` syntax in SSH configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the keywords in the ssh config file support environment variables, but most do not. Fortunately IndentyFile is one of them.

You need to use `${HOME}` rather than `$HOME` in the file.

You can also use `tokens`, such as `%d` to refer to the home directory. This is documented by `man ssh_config`.

Comment: tried `${HOME}` already. also not working

Comment: For me this worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add, there are two further things one can do thanks to the `-F` options (custom config file) of ssh, especially as the variables do not work in the ancient yet ubiquitous CentOS 7. This is important when one is a node with no home (but with $HOME pointing to an non-existent place).
In an HTCondor cluster, $_CONDOR_SCRATCH_DIR is your home for example, not $HOME. etc.

Filepaths can be relative, so one could `cd` into the directory you wish and use relative paths.

```
ssh -F relative_ssh.config servername
```

The second is expand using `envsubst`

```
FOO=1 BAR=2 envsubst < in_file > out_file
```

However, this command, like `ssh` in many Singularity containers, is absent in stripped down systems (`yum/apt-get install utils-linux` or `yum/apt-get update` if a Singularity build).

Finally the obvious PSA: storing ssh keys and configurations in a remote server/cluster/machine is dangerous. Never leave them in a shared space, unless you are 100% adamant nobody has sudo rights on any machine that volume is mounted. OBfuScAt1on can help (e.g. nobody will look in
a folder called `crash-dump-Aug23`), but actually encrypting the tarball say with `openssl` (which is present on barebone systems).